# SQL query to relate timestamped events in a table from a SQLITE database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database in SQLITE (lets call it params) that stores a list of parameter changes and the times that they changed. ie:

```
key    paramid    time    val
---    -------    ----    ---
1      7          1.2     0
2      3          2.5     23
3      3          5.6     54
4      3          7.1     76
5      7          8.4     1
6      3          9.2     33
7      9          9.7     22
8      3          10.3    21
```

I would like to use a query to generate a table that includes every time one parameter changed along with the value of the other parameter when the first parameter changed and the time of the change.  ie:

```
param3Val    latestParam7Val    time
---------    ---------------    ----
23           0                  2.5
54           0                  5.6
76           0                  7.1
33           1                  9.2
21           1                  10.3
```

Any ideas for doing this efficiently in SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there always gonna be only 2 parameters?. If not, then what would "the value of the other parameter" mean?

Comment: You example (IMHO) doesn't help us to understand what you want...

Comment: No, there will be many different parameters and I'd like to be able to choose any of them and look at them with respect to any other.  I've just used two here for simplicity.

Comment: Do you have an id for each row? I mean, a unique id for every row (not paramid)

Comment: yes.  There is a primary key as well.

Comment: I've updated the table with another unused paramid (9) and a primary key to clarify.

Comment: @Joey - You added another parameter, but you still have only 2 columns, param3val and latestParam7val. So, are you always wanna compare just 2 parameters?

Comment: Yes.  But which parameters are compared could change.  I may want to look at the latest values of 7 for each time 9 changed for example, or the latest values of 3 for each time 7 changes.  The names of the tables in the query result are just to clarify what I pulled out in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT p1.val
     , (SELECT p2.val
          FROM params p2
         WHERE p2.paramid = 7
           AND p2.time < p1.time
         ORDER BY p2.time DESC
         LIMIT 1
       ) latestParam7Val
     , p1.time
  FROM params p1
```

Alternative with joins:

```
SELECT p1.val
     , p2.val
     , p1.time
  FROM params p1
  LEFT JOIN params p2 ON p2.paramid = 7 AND p2.time < p1.time
  LEFT JOIN params p3 ON p3.paramid = 7 AND p3.time < p1.time
                                        AND p3.time > p2.time
 WHERE p3.time IS NULL
```

Comment: This makes sense.  I am concerned about the query time though.  Theoretically I could perform this query in linear time by just incrementing through the table and always storing the latest value of 7 while I add rows when I hit 3s.  Would the SQL queries that you suggested run in linear or (n squared) time?

Comment: @Joey: The optimizer knows. Depends on your indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.val AS param3Val,
    (SELECT t2.val AS latestParam7Val
     FROM your_table t2
     WHERE t2.paramid <> t1.paramid
       AND t2.key < t1.key
     ORDER BY t2.key DESC
     LIMIT 1), t1.time
FROM your_table t1
ORDER BY t1.key
```

Comment: Your solution had some minor issues that I fixed for peer edit.  It is equivalent to the first solution presented by Benoit.